# How to find a previous file based on the filename's pattern with javascript

Tags: javascript, file-io

This seems like it would be a popular thing to do, but I'm not finding any examples.

Given a folder with a series of files, all of which start with a timestamp:

> YYYY-MM-DD_SomeOtherText.md

The folder contains:

- `2023-07-01_Subject3.md`
- `2023-07-02_Subject2.md`
- `2023-07-03_Subject1_Topic1.md`
- `2023-07-04_Subject1_Topic2.md`
- `2023-07-04_Subject2.md`

My objective is that the next time I create a new document on Subject2, I would like run a javascript function<sup>1</sup> to know what the date was of the previous note regarding Subject2.

The catch is, when I create this document, it will be called `2023-07-05_Subject2.md` and will exist prior to any javascript being run. So the filename/date I need would actually be the second in the list files (or the current title is disqualified by the function somehow).

I can't use metadata, like date created or modified, as sometimes files will be created out of order, or in mass. And files will get modified at any time.

---

<sup>1</sup> Don't get hung up on how the javascript is run after creating a note. This is for a note-taking app called [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/) which will do that for me. I just need the vanilla (not Node.js) javascript that would get the previous file name.